# Show that $i/2m\int d^3\vec x\hat\pi(\vec x)\partial^2_i\hat\phi(\vec x)=1/(2\pi)^3\int d^3\vec p E(\vec p)\hat a(\vec p)^\dagger\hat a(\vec p)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, hamiltonian, fourier-transform

Show that the quantum field for the Hamiltonian, $$\hat H=\frac{i}{2m}\int d^3 \vec x\hat{\pi}(\vec x)\partial^2_i\hat{\phi}(\vec x)\tag{1}$$
can be written as $$\int  \frac{d^3\vec p}{(2\pi)^3}E(\vec p) \hat a(\vec p)^\dagger\hat a(\vec p)\tag{2}$$ where $$E(\vec p)=\frac{\vec p^2}{2m}$$

$$\hat{\phi}(\vec x)=\int\frac{d^3\vec p}{(2\pi)^3}e^{i\vec p \cdot \vec x}\hat a(\vec p)\tag{3}$$

$$\hat{\pi}(\vec x)=i\hat{\phi}(\vec x)^\dagger=i\int\frac{d^3\vec p}{(2\pi)^3}e^{-i\vec p \cdot \vec x}\hat a(\vec p)^\dagger\tag{4}$$

---

Differentiating $(3)$ wrt $\vec x$ twice gives
$$\partial^2_i\hat\phi(\vec x)=-\int\frac{d^3\vec p}{(2\pi)^3}\vec p^2e^{i\vec p \cdot \vec x}\hat a(\vec p)\tag{5}$$

But now I can't seem to arrive at equation $(2)$ by direct substitution of $(4)$ and $(5)$ into $(1)$, as this leads to quite a mess:
$$\begin{align}\hat H &= \frac{i}{2m}\int d^3 \vec x\hat{\pi}(\vec x)\partial^2_i\hat{\phi}(\vec x)\\&=\frac{1}{2m}\int d^3 \vec x \int\frac{d^3\vec p}{(2\pi)^3}e^{-i\vec p \cdot \vec x}\hat a(\vec p)^\dagger\int\frac{d^3\vec p}{(2\pi)^3}\vec p^2e^{i\vec p \cdot \vec x}\hat a(\vec p)\\&=\int d^3 \vec x \int\frac{d^3\vec p}{(2\pi)^3}\hat a(\vec p)^\dagger\int\frac{d^3\vec p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{\vec p^2}{2m}\hat a(\vec p)\\&=\color{red}{\int d^3 \vec x \int\frac{d^3\vec p}{(2\pi)^3}\int\frac{d^3\vec p}{(2\pi)^3}E(\vec p)\hat a(\vec p)^\dagger\hat a(\vec p)}\\&\ne \int\frac{d^3\vec p}{(2\pi)^3}E(\vec p)\hat a(\vec p)^\dagger\hat a(\vec p)\end{align}$$

Which apart from the last integral after the fourth equality is identical to $(2)$. In the second to third equality I cancelled the exponentials and in the third to fourth equality I commuted the $\hat a(\vec p)^\dagger$ past $E(\vec p)$ $\left(=\frac{\vec p^2}{2m}\right)$ which I think is justified since it is a scalar.

But it is this triple integral that is bothering me here, I'm simply not sure how to deal with this.

If the logic demonstrated above is wrong then my other thought is to Fourier transform $(3)$ and $(4)$ to get explicit expressions for $\hat a(\vec p)$ and $\hat a(\vec p)^\dagger$, which, in the case of $(3)$ will give $$\hat a(\vec p)=\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^3}\int d^3 \vec x \hat \phi(\vec x)e^{-i\vec p \cdot \vec x}$$ but when trying to Fourier transform $(5)$ (to get an expression for $\hat a(\vec p)$) I get a different result, which suggests I am again doing something wrong.

---

I deliberately chose to ask this on P.SE instead of M.SE as I thought it would be better placed in physics, but if this is felt to be a mistake then the question can be migrated.

I have typeset all the details relevant for this question, but if specific sources from which I drew the information are requested then I will be more than happy to upload the required background info :-)

In short, how do I obtain eqn. $(2)$ from $(1)$, please?

Comment: Your first step, (5), is incorrect. You can’t pull $\vec p^2$ out of an integral over $\vec p$. Following that, you’ve reused $\vec p$ as an integration variable in two different integrals.

Comment: @Ghoster Okay thank you, mistake in eqn. $(5)$ noted and understood. Moreover, I agree, I cannot use $\vec p$ as an integration variable for 2 integrals. I could have put ${\vec p'}$ or something to make it distinct, but the point is I really don't know how to proceed on from there. Thank you for pointing out these mistakes though, it is appreciated. Now I just need to know what is the correct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int~d^3\vec{x}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}e^{i(\vec{p}-\vec{q})\cdot\vec{x}}=\delta^3(\vec{p}-\vec{q}) \tag 1$$

---

\begin{align}
H&=\int d^3\vec{x}\frac{d^3\vec{p}~d^3\vec{q}}{(2\pi)^3(2\pi)^3}\frac{i}{2m}(i)e^{-i\vec{q}\cdot \vec{x}}a^\dagger(\vec{q})(-1)\vec{p}^2e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}a(\vec{p}) \tag 2 \\
&=\int d^3\vec{p}~d^3\vec{q}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{\vec{p}^2}{2m}a^\dagger_{\vec{q}}a_{\vec{p}}\delta^3(\vec{p}-\vec{q}) \tag 3\\
&=\int \frac{d^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3}~E_{\vec{p}}a^\dagger(\vec{p})a(\vec{p}) \tag 4
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't quite follow your logic however, what is $\vec q$ here? Would you mind showing a few more steps on how this triple integral reduces to a single integral? Your answer, while clear to others is not yet obvious to me, thank you.

Comment: both $p$ and $q$ are dummy variables for momentum. One is used in your field, one in its canonical momentum conjugate. This should solve the issue pointed out by @Ghoster that you reused your integration variables and lead you to the answer you want.

Comment: Okay, but how does the triple integral in the steps (now marked red) in my post reduce to a single integral? I.e. what happened to the $\int d^3 \vec x $ part? I'm only trying to understand how to obtain $(2)$ from $(1)$. Thank you!

Comment: It reduces to a single integral because you can change your order of integration to reduce firstly the triple integral to a double integral involving the delta distribution. Then you can use the property of the delta distribution to reduce it to a single integral.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and comments, but I am really struggling to understand what you are saying. Would it be too much trouble to ask you to include these extra steps in your answer, specifically showing how it reduces to a single integral?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed response, just a few closing questions, in going from your eqn. $(3)$ to $(4)$ did you use the 'sifting' property of the Dirac-delta: $\int~d^3\vec{q}\delta^3(\vec{p}-\vec{q})\hat a^\dagger(\vec{q})= \hat a^\dagger(\vec{p})$? Secondly, what happened to the integration symbols in your equations $(2)$ - $(4)$, ie. are those typo's or is the omission of those integration symbols some kind of standard (shorthand) notation?

Comment: 1. Yes it’s the property of delta distribution. 2. Yes I did not write down all the $\int$ because you could readily tell how many of them should be present by looking at how many $d^3$ are there.